# I can not see the reputation and badges from an Android phone

Tags: support, mobile-web, top-bar, android

I can not see my reputation points nor badges from my Android Phone on the black strip at the top of the page.

[image: Android]

But they are displayed when the page in seen on my PC:

[image: PC]

Is this a change in feature or is there some specific reason for this? I hope that it's not some kind of problem from my end. This question is only for Android smartphones with the Chrome browser.